# Login on AWS Cognito via Facebook problem

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, facebook-login, amazon-cognito

I have a problem with login via Facebook with AWS Cognito.

The login page is https://magazzinoperfetto.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=7ii0p2ob77m2d1ashv9708e5b&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https://www.magazzinoperfetto.it&response_type=code&state=TWFnYXp6aW5vIFBlcmZldHRvIExvZ2lu

but when I click on Login via Facebook I receive this error: URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings.

As you can see https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlmEb.jpg I have set the domain in whitelist but the problem persist.

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you try whitelisting `<COGNITO_DOMAIN>/oauth2/idpresponse`?

Comment: `https://magazzinoperfetto.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse` is the actual `redirect_uri` value when I trigger the Facebook login dialog from the mentioned page.

Comment: @Giovanni Did you found solution for your problem.